# CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy fails to process array / dictionary containing NSNull

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, core-foundation

For some reason this sample code works:

```
NSArray *immutable = @[ @"a", @"b", @"c" ];
NSMutableArray *mutable = (__bridge  id)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge  CFArrayRef)immutable, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

and this code produces `nil` as a result of the conversion:

```
NSArray *immutable = @[ @"a", [NSNull null], @"c" ];
NSMutableArray *mutable = (__bridge  id)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge  CFArrayRef)immutable, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
```

I tried to find any mention of `NSNull` not being allowed when using this function. I have a suspicion that it has something to do with the way method examines whether property is mutable or not, but I can't really back that up with facts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As kind people from apple developer forum pointed out the issue is that Property List Structure is rather strict about data types it can work with. `NSNull` is not one of allowed ones.

From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/StructureAndContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001171-CJBEJBHH):

> Property lists are constructed from the basic Core Foundation types `CFString`, `CFNumber`, `CFBoolean`, `CFDate`, and `CFData`.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative or a workaround to accept a null value, because we're using this on data from a JSON API which has `null` in some places?

Comment: according to this source http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFPropertyList.c (search for CFPropertyListRef CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy) it's not quite possible. Maybe try replacing null with predefined constant that is unlikely to be encountered in your data set?